# installation oracle-19c on oraclelinux

Tags: oracle

when installing oracle 19 c on oraclelinux
I received an error message when calling the target 'libasmclntsh19.ohso
In the log file
I have as info: oracle.install.ivw.common.driver.job.Installerpatchjob
checkStatus
INFO: The home patch status is clean
how to cure it

installation of oracle on oraclelinux

Comment: What version of Oracle Linux are you using? At what point in the installation did the error occur? Are there any other details in the installer log file? As it is, you haven't given us enough information to help you. It also isn't clear that this is a software development problem and not a database or operating system issue, which would be more appropriately asked about on other forums like https://dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: i am using oraclelinux 8,
the message is displayed during oracle 19c installation progress.